# extracting images from camera using fpga and trasfering to pc

Tags: fpga, spartan

am be student,ece. In our college we have spartan 6-150Tx series fpga kit , the software used for this is Xilinx ise... this kit has a camera too, we need to connect this camera to fpga kit and further my work is to grab images using this camera using fpga and then view the same images on my computer ..how exactly i can do this ? do i need to write any algorithm ? if yes, pls help me out how exactly can i do this ?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail about your situation: links to all of the products in question, and a detailed description of what you've tried so far. Didn't the kit come with any example code that does at least part of what you need to accomplish? As it stands, your question is far too vague to attempt an answer.

Comment: What does the dev board manual say? Typically they have sample code for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 8):

Let me be completely honest with you, @lavanya.  I'm not doing this to be mean, or to be grumpy-- so don't take this too personally.  But it is important for you (and others like you) to understand why people don't want to answer your question.

The main problem with your question is two fold:  1. It is an extremely broad question.  And 2. It shows a lack of "foundational knowledge".  What I mean by foundational knowledge is that you lack the basic knowledge to even talk about the subject.  Put a different way, we would spend the whole time giving you definitions to words and discussing basic concepts instead of actually answering your question.

Let me rephrase your question to give you a better example of how we see your question:  "I have some seeds, some dirt, a pile of cow poo, a pocket knife, and a Sperry-New Holland XKZ-4000 Combine.  How can I make a Birthday Cake?"

See?  You want a birthday cake, but we'd have to discuss biochemistry, crop rotation, seasonal precipitation patterns, Malliard reactions, and gluten protein structures.

A proper answer to your question would require several books, and cannot be answered in the space of a typical answer here.

It seems like you're in some sort of class.  I suggest that you use the class to learn the basics and the overall approach to your project.  Then ask specific questions here; questions that can be answered in a reasonable length of text.

Comment: Also things like lower case "i" and texting-style like "pls" doesn't help the chances of people wanting to spend time on this question.